# Conditional ignore in Git

Tags: git

I'd like to know of there is a way to configure Git to ignore certain folders conditionnally.
I am thinking for example to check if a directory has a file called '.exclude' or something that would get the directory exlude from Git commits.

Thanks.

Comment: Any reason why you can't add the directories to `.gitignore`?

Comment: I wanted to minimize the changes done to .gitignore as those directories are numerous and changing very often.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just put a `.gitignore` file with a `*` entry in the folder you want to ignore. They can be anywhere in the repository, not just the top level.

Comment: Yeah, I guess my question was stupid. Thought did not even occur to me. Thanks Amber, I'm going to the coffee machine now.

Comment: Wait, that won't exclude the directory itself though, will it?

Comment: Directories are not tracked by git, only directories content. So if all the files in the directory are ignored, it is also ignored.

Comment: To be specific: not even the .gitignore file will be tracked by git if it's the only file inside that directory and it reads `*`